# Table of contents with page number - how to implement

Tags: jasper-reports

Is it possible to implement Table of contents with page number on first page of the PDF report?

I've read the below links and refered in google:

1) http://community.jaspersoft.com/questions/541300/table-contents-ireport
2) http://community.jaspersoft.com/questions/529040/generation-page-numbers-table-content

On first link, They are using **scriptlets** for this. I want **Table of contents with page number** on the **first page of pdf report**. But I do not understand where to start. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend you checking [this](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/sample.reference/tableofcontents/index.html) sample from the original documentation.

There is no way (or at least I don't know/haven't found how) to generate the Table of Contents at the beginning (since there is no way to know the pages numbers). So you will have to generate it at the end (in the summary band) and move it afterwards to where you want to place it. To move it use [JasperPrint](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/api/net/sf/jasperreports/engine/JasperPrint.html) class, methods getPages, addPage, removePage.

I guess you will have subreports, if so, you need to pass the JRBeanCollectionDataSource you will be filling during runtime to each subreport (and return the value back to the master report).

Hope that helps.

Comment: yes Drewich. You are right. There is no very good example outside except jasper report. Jasper report community have provided example for each item in jasper report. You can check this http://sourceforge.net/projects/jasperreports/files/jasperreports/ .. Download your jasper report which comes with many examples like Scriptlet and tableofcontents. Nice tutorial too.